# How to avoid messy error handling in Tornado RequestHandler

Tags: python, error-handling, tornado

Say I have a simple `RequestHandler` like this.

```
class RequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id, status):
        obj = self.retrieve_object(id)
        obj.update({"status": status})
        self.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

Problem is, whenever there's an error in the handler, it's gonna return an error 500 (Internal server error). Obviously I want to return an error 400 instead when the user has inputted something invalid.

So I have to add a bunch of error checking, like this:

```
class RequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id, status):
        try:
            id = int(id)
        except ValueError:
            raise web.HTTPError(400, "Invalid id")
        if status not in ("open", "closed"):
            raise web.HTTPError(400, "Invalid status")

        try:
            obj = self.retrieve_object(id)
        except ObjDoesntExistError:
            raise web.HTTPError(400, "Object doesn't exist")

        obj.update({"status": status})
        self.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

The issue is that this adds a lot of bloat to the function. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or is it unavoidable?

Comment: You can compress the `try` `except` blocks to 2 lines, but the reality is the more you check for the more code you have.  Alternative is to put into a separate "checker" or "helper" module (where all the bloat is contained) and import that.

Comment: @D.L yep I figured that would be the case. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Comment: If you can think of a better (or cleaner) way, please do post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform the same checks in multiple handlers, you can just create a base class:

```py
class BaseHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        id = self.path_args[0]
        status = self.path_args[1]

        try:
            id = int(id)
        except ValueError:
            raise web.HTTPError(400, "Invalid id")
        
        # ... and so on ...
```

Now, just inherit from this base class and the code will be reused.